# Calculate the percentage of categories in a column in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have a table, `colors` in Hive that looks like this:

```
 id cname
 1 Blue
 2 Green
 3 Green
 4 Blue
 5 Blue
```

I need help with writing a Hive query that gives the percentages of each color in the cname column. Something that looks like this:

```
Blue  60%
Green 40%
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using analytics functions:

```
select cname, concat(pct, ' %') pct
from
(
select (
        count(*) over (partition by cname)/
        count(*) over ()
       )*100 as pct,
       cname
  from (--Replace this subquery with your table
        select stack (5,
                      1, 'Blue',
                      2, 'Green',
                      3, 'Green',
                      4, 'Blue',
                      5, 'Blue' )  as (id, cname)

        ) colors
)s
group by cname, pct;
```

Result:

```
OK
Blue    60.0 %
Green   40.0 %
```

Just replace `colors` subquery with your table