# calculate row percentage in hive

Tags: hive

I want to calculate percentage of each row to column total in total. Here it's my code

```
SELECT a, a/(SELECT SUM(a) FROM table b) AS percentage
FROM table b
```

it returns

> cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'SUM' '(' in expression
>   specification

[https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Subqueries+in+SELECT subqueries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Subqueries+in+SELECT) It says subqueriesin complex expressions, aggregates, UDFs, etc. will not be supported by Hive.

How to fix it?

Comment: Check this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52467805/2700344

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum` analytic function. An empty `OVER()` clause sums up the values of a given column across all rows.

```
SELECT a, a/SUM(a) OVER() AS percentage
FROM table
```